# Selenium: How to click a label

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to click this object with selenium (pyhton) using the code:

```
driver.find_element_by_('publicForm_customFields').click()
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> id="publicForm_customFields" tabindex="0" type="radio" value="value"> is not clickable at point (480, 98). Other element would receive the click: value

Comment: The html is
<div class="pp-radio pp-display-inline-block"><input name="customFields" id="publicForm_customFields" tabindex="0" type="radio" value="value">
<label for="publicForm_customFields" title="">
value
</label></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Other element would receive the click" means that you have another element over your element. There are a couple of options to get around this:

1. Try to find another element above in the DOM tree and click on it.
2. Use js click, you need to write a function like this:

```
 def js_click(self, element):
        element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

js script will click on the element even if it is intersected by another

Answer (score 0):

There might be two possibilities:

1- Your locator to find element might be wrong or not unique.
2- You need to apply explicit wait till element is ready [load successfully] to be clickable.

Hope above possibilities might help you out, Or you share the link of the sight so I might debug correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any find method to the driver. Try refactoring the code to:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('publicForm_customFields').click()
```

Also, try using some sort of wait so the driver does not click before the page/element is loaded.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'publicForm_customFields'))).click()
```